# Access Azure app variables in spring application.properties

Tags: spring, azure

Is is possible to access Azzure app settings variables in spring boot application.properties?
[Azzure app settings variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4lWk.png)

like this?
[application.properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vMqj.png)